# Ansible 2.9.7 on RHEL 7.9 - Upgrade plan

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.9.7 is running on RHEL 7.9 server.
We are planning to upgrade the Ansible to latest version.

As per documentation, there are many Ansible versions released after 2.9.7 and latest one is Ansible 7 (ansible-core and ansible).

Can you advise which version would be the appropriate one to upgrade from 2.9.7 on the existing RHEL 7.9 server ? Does latest Ansible versions support RHEL 7.9 ?

Comment: Since this question is not about programming it might fit better on superuser.com, serverfault.com or devops.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can you advise which version would be the appropriate one to upgrade from 2.9.7 on the existing RHEL 7.9 server?*

This will depend on your environment and capabilities.

... just like to note that within Enterprise Packages for Linux (EPEL) a version with bug fixes is available, Ansible v2.9.27.

```bash
~/test$ yum provides ansible
...
ansible-2.9.27-1.el7.noarch : SSH-based configuration management, deployment, and task execution system
Repo        : EPEL-7
```

> *Does latest Ansible versions support RHEL 7.9?*

Since it is written in Python it is somehow agnostic about the underlying OS, but it will [depend on the Python version installed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html).

If you don't plan to install another Python environment and stay with the distributed version from the OS, Python 2.7, then you are bound up to Ansible v2.11. See Ansible Community Topic Issue #[54](https://github.com/ansible-community/community-topics/issues/54).

```bash
~/test$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
~/test$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.12]
  config file = /home/user/test/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 27 2022, 11:27:32) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True
```

If you can install another Python environment you can use higher Ansible versions.

Please take note that certain modules, Ansible Galaxy, Collections, etc. may have own requirements and dependencies.

**Further Documentation Links**

- [Installing Ansible - Prerequisites](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#prerequisites) (v2.9)
- [Installing Ansible - Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements) (latest)
- [Releases and maintenance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html) (latest)